# Email clients for Dynamics AX

Tags: smtpclient, axapta

I am wondering how the process of sending email is working between Dynamics Ax client and Email client that is set for the server as default email client.

First of all can Dynamics Ax use alternative email clients (not outlook) for sending emails and second of all is Dynamics Ax sending whole configuration to the client, or client has to be configured by itself.

Right now I am experiencing unknown error while trying to send email using Windows Live Mail.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamics AX uses [MAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mapi.aspx) for *client* mail.

You can use the `SysINetMail::sendEMail` method to send a simple mail using this.

If you mail in batch another option is to use SMTP mail using `SysEmailTable::sendMail`.
This requires the use of mail templates.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but if someone else needs it...
I am using this on a Dynamics AX 2009 and it works like a charm :)

```
server static boolean sendEmail(EmplId _fromEmplId, EmplId _toEmplId, str _subject, str message, EmailPriority _priority = EmailPriority::Normal)
{
boolean         ok = true;
SysEmailBatch   emailBatch;
EmplTable       fromEmplTable;
EmplTable       toEmplTable;
Email           fromEmail;
Email           toEmail;
;

changecompany( -- TO YOUR MASTER COMPANY --)
{
    fromEmplTable   = EmplTable::find(_fromEmplId);
    toEmplTable     = EmplTable::find(_toEmplId);
    fromEmail       = fromEmplTable.email();
    toEmail         = toEmplTable.email();

    if (! fromEmail)
    {
        ok = checkFailed(strfmt("no email set up for %1", _fromEmplId));
    }

    if (! toEmail)
    {
        ok = checkFailed(strfmt("no email set up for %1", _toEmplId));
    }

    if (ok)
    {
        emailBatch = SysEmailBatch::construct();

        emailBatch.parmSendername(fromEmplTable.name());
        emailBatch.parmSenderAddr(fromEmplTable.email());
        emailBatch.parmEmailAddr(toEmplTable.email());

        emailBatch.parmPriority(_priority);
        emailBatch.parmSubject(_subject);
        emailBatch.parmMessageBody(_message);

        emailBatch.run();
    }
}

return ok;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SysOutgoingEmailTable and SysOutgoingEmailData you can send email to recipient of any domain and attach files too.

you have following fields:

```
outgoingEmailTable.EmailItemId
outgoingEmailTable.IsSystemEmail
outgoingEmailTable.Sender 
outgoingEmailTable.SenderName 
outgoingEmailTable.Recipient
outgoingEmailTable.Subject 
outgoingEmailTable.Priority 
outgoingEmailTable.WithRetries 
outgoingEmailTable.RetryNum
outgoingEmailTable.UserId
outgoingEmailTable.Status 
outgoingEmailTable.Message
outgoingEmailTable.TemplateId
outgoingEmailTable.LatestStatusChangeDateTime 

outgoingEmailData.EmailItemId
outgoingEmailData.FileName
outgoingEmailData.EmailDataType
outgoingEmailData.FileExtension
```

insert respective email detail in these tables and you are good to go. Further if it gives permission error do add permission set with 
   CodeAccessPermission::assertMultiple .